# Graphite group timestamp events by week

Tags: grafana, graphite

TLDR: How can I group a graphite timestamp metric by week/month instead of having it appear day by day for a given time period?

Detail: I have an anomaly I'm interested in investigating but because my report is for a 60 day time period, I'm seeing too many spikes. I'd like to see a 60 day report but aggregate the metrics per week or month. How can I do that?

I've tried the Graphite documentation but cannot seem to find what I'm looking for

[image: Something interesting]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [summarize function](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.summarize) allows you to choose an aggregation method over a specified time period (day, week, etc). This should be helpful to you here.